# How to do an incremental sum on a datetime column in Excel

Tags: excel, datetime, timestamp, sum

I have a datetime stamp in a column. I am trying to do an incremental sum of the  interval between the timestamps in Excel. Please help me with the formula to do that. I have just hard coded it by calculating manually.

`+--------------------+----------+
|     TimeStamp      | Interval |
+--------------------+----------+
| 7/31/2014 6:58:48  |        1 |
| 7/31/2014 6:58:52  |        4 |
| 7/31/2014 6:58:54  |        6 |
| 7/31/2014 6:58:57  |        9 |
| 7/31/2014 6:59:00  |       12 |
| 7/31/2014 6:59:03  |       15 |
| 7/31/2014 6:59:06  |       18 |
| 7/31/2014 6:59:10  |       22 |
+--------------------+----------+`

Comment: something like `=SECOND(A2-A1)+B1`? starting in `B2`

Comment: Alright I will post that as the answer then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SECOND` formula is what you should be using:

```
=SECOND("date string")
```

It takes in a date and gives you the amount of seconds for the date.

If you take `=SECOND(date2 - date1)` you get the delta of seconds between the dates.

Since you want to sum up all deltas up to the current row you can use:

```
=SECOND(A2-A1)+B1
```

And auto-fill down (of course change the cell references based on your data)